# Xorg 1.17.4: launched with startx -- -seat seat1, but why doesn't loginctl show "seat1"?

Tags: xorg, systemd, multiseat

I'm looking to add a separate X instance and a seat to a running system.

```
$ startx -- :9 -novtswitch -sharevts -seat seat1
```

Things launch OK, but `loginctl` doesn't show the seat anywhere.

```
$ [-] loginctl
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
       147       1000 leho                             
        16       1007 media            seat0           
         3       1000 leho                             
       146       1000 leho                             
         2       1001 lembit                           
         4       1000 leho                             
        15       1007 media            seat0           
         1       1008 anna-maria                       

8 sessions listed.
```

Should it not? I can't do my desired device partitioning if the new seat doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

actually, the command to list seats is `loginctl list-seats`

PRO Tip: when things don't work in Terminal, try ...command... -help or -h or --help or help, or man ...command...